# Ionic Component Flagged as Potential Scroll Performance Bottleneck When Similar "Button" Is Not

Tags: performance, ionic3

I've been trying to get the scroll performance on my Ionic app up to par. I'm using the Google Chrome Rendering option under "More Tools" to flag potential scroll performance bottlenecks. I've found an issue with the touch events on a component. What's odd is this component is very similar to buttons that are on the same page, in the same scrollable section. They both have (click) and tappable attributes. It may be important to note that the component is also swipeable. When I turn off the swipeable feature, the issue goes away.

Is there any way I can fix this issue without disabling the swipeable feature? Also, there is another issue where Chrome flags all the (click)able links inside the swipeable component as potential scroll bottlenecks.

The URL Is https://musicblobs.com/home/HeyYouYeahYou. Here's an image of my issue:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pK8ms.png)

Comment: Can you elaborate which specific component you mean here! Ion list or?

Comment: It's a custom component inside of an ion-list with ion-swiping feature